# How to make a deep-const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, transitive-const

Let's say I want to represent a binary tree in C++. Usually, I want a `Node` struct like this:

```cpp
struct Node {
  Node* left
  Node* right;
};
```

(Here I use struct and raw pointers just for simplicity. I know I should use smart pointers for memory management.)

This representation has a problem: I can never have a deep-`const` tree. (Correct me if I can.) I may mark a single `Node` const, but its children is hard-coded as non-`const` in the `Node` struct.

(I may use some `template` hack to make `left` and `right` optionally `const`, but this makes the const `Node` and non-`const` `Node` incompatible.)

Soon I found out, if I magically had some deep-`const` pointer (say `deep_const_pointer`, which makes `const`ness transitive), I can use that pointer in `Node` so that having a `const` node automatically means having a `const` sub-tree.

I tried to write a deep-`const` pointer class, and here is what I end up with:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class deep_const_pointer {
public:
  explicit deep_const_pointer(const T* p_)
    : p{const_cast<T*>(p_)} {}

  const T& operator*() const { return *p; }
  T& operator*() { return *p; }

  const T* operator->() const { return p; }
  T* operator->() { return p; }

  // etc.

private:
  T* p;
};
```

Here I cast out the `const` in the constructor and optionally add it back according to the `const`ness of this pointer-like object. However, this implementation allows the following:

```cpp
const int i = 42;
deep_const_pointer<int> p{&i};
*p = 0; // Oops!
```

So it depends on the user to correctly mark whether the pointer is `const` or not.

How should I build a deep-`const` pointer class? Ideally, I want the `const` check happen at compile-time, and that pointer class takes as much memory as a raw pointer. (Which rules out the solution to save the `const`ness to a `bool` member variable and check on each access.)

**EDIT**: I checked `std::experimental::propagate_const`, and it is indeed not a "deep-const" pointer from my perspective. What I meant by deep-const pointer `P` is:

1. Constant `P` is pointer-to-const;
2. Mutable `P` is pointer-to-mutable;
3. A const reference to a non-const `P` is treated as if it were a const `P`;
4. Since pointer-to-const has value semantics, a const `P` should be trivially copyable.

`propagate_const` fails to match the requirement because:

1. It never accepts a pointer-to-const;
2. It is not copyable (copy constructors explicitly deleted);

From the comments and answer I received, I guess such a `P` is not implementable in C++.

Comment: How about making a `const` and non-`const` getter for child-nodes? If a `Node` is given as `const`, only the latter could be used, and those would always return pointer to `const`. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: How about using [`std::experimental::propagate_const<>`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const), a smart-pointer for transitive const? That seems to get it right.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, I did not know about that! I cannot use these experimental features, unfortunately. I will read the implementation to get some insights.

Comment: "Let's say I want to represent a binary tree in C++. Usually, I want a Node struct like this:" - I'd say you'd usually want to use a `std::set` or `std::map` or some other standard node based container. *Not* roll your own.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I should not have said "binary tree". I am actually working on an abstract syntax tree (AST), so a `std::set` or `std::map` is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a transitive-`const` smart pointer is a solved problem, just look up [`std::experimental::propagate_const<>`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const). It shouldn't be too hard to find appropriate implementations.

In your own try, you got constructing from a raw pointer wrong. You should not add `const` to the pointee-type, nor strip it out with a cast.
Fixed:

```
explicit deep_const_pointer(T* p_)
    : p{p_} {}
```

Comment: But in this way will a `const deep_const_pointer<Node>` be constructible from a `const Node*` pointer?

Comment: @Krantz No, and it should not be. Allowing that is a bug.

Comment: I'm confused. For example, did you mean `std::experimental::propagate_const<int>` should always point to a non-`const` `int`, but treat it as a constant according to the constness of the `propagate_const` object? That sounds strange to me.

Comment: I meant that I should be able to have const nodes, but if this `propagate_const` does not accept const nodes, I will be forced to create nodes in a const subtree as non-const nodes, and *that* sounds really strange to me.