# Pointer to a const object can change the object?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

A pointer to a const object doesn't allow to change the object. For example:

```cpp
class foo {
    public:
        int m_data;
        
        foo() : m_data{11} {}
};

void change(const foo *obj)
{
    obj -> m_data = 21;   // gives error, normal
}
```

This is fine and normal behavior.

What I don't understand is that when we add an additional pointer variable, either of the same type (like `foo *`) or of some other type (like `bar *`), but not the basic types like `int *`, then we can change the value that the pointer points to (from a pointer to the const type itself).

How is this possible?

```cpp
class foo {
    public:
        int m_data;
        foo *m_next;
        
        foo() : m_data{11}, m_next{nullptr} {}
};

void change(const foo *obj)
{
    obj -> m_next -> m_data = 21;   // does not give any error! why?
}
```

This also happens if we take some other type inside `foo`, like `bar *`.

Why is this happening? How can I define the function so that I can be sure that my function can't change the value the object is pointing to?

Comment: You're not changing `m_next` or anything else in `*obj`. The `foo` being `const` means that you couldn't, for instance, reassign `m_next` to point to something else. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476869/constant-pointer-vs-pointer-to-constant) or similar questions for more on the distinction.

Comment: `const`ness is not transitive

Comment: About how to make a deep-const pointer: [How to make a deep-const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505046/how-to-make-a-deep-const-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

```
obj -> m_next -> m_data = 21;   // does not give any error! why?
```

Because this is not changing the object. This object's `m_next` pointer is exactly the same as it was before.

This is only changing whatever `m_next` is pointing to. Which has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the object that owns this `m_next` pointer.

Now, if, on the other hand, you try to assign something to the `m_next` pointer itself, instead of whatever it's pointing to, then you'll get the error you were expecting.

The only thing that the object contains are its enumerated members. None of them are changed by this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `foo* m_next` is a pointer member variable to a mutable `foo` object. The pointer itself is considered part of the object instance, not the object being pointed to.

By changing `m_next`, you are changing the pointer, which is considered part of the instance of `foo`. Doing something like `obj->m_next = nullptr;` in `change` would be invalid because you are changing the memory that is part of the constant `foo` instance. (Note: don't don't set random pointers to null in real code, unless you're sure it's safe, or it's a possible memory leak).

By accessing the object being pointed to by `m_next` via `m_next->`, you are accessing memory of another object that is not part of the const instance passed to `change`. This is perfectly valid.

You could say that constness is not transitive; a const object doesn't make objects accessed through it (via pointers) const.