# How can I make a const class work properly with referenced data?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, constants, transitive-const

Let's say I have an image class which references a buffer containing a huge amount of data.

When the copy constructor is called, it would be nice not to have to copy the data unless that was absolutely necessary.

However, if I construct a new image object from an existing const object, the new image object begins in non-const state, which allows the image data in the new object to be altered, even though the image data in the old object could not.

I believe this is a fundamental problem in C++, because the shared_ptr object has the same problem: if you are handed a const shared_ptr, you only need to copy it into a non-const shared_ptr (via a constructor) to obtain a mutable object, which seems an insidious way to counteract const-correctness. Raw pointers do not have this problem, as such a copy is not allowed.

I understand that pointer members inherently do not inherit constness from their owner, but what I am after is a way to construct a class to make it appear that they do, to make it easy to ensure that the contents of a const object remain const.

This question provides a partial answer to this question, as it suggests using `std::experimental::propagate_const` to ensure that a pointer in a const object becomes a const pointer:

[How to make a deep-const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505046/how-to-make-a-deep-const-pointer)

However, I believe this does not solve the problem of how to ensure that a copy constructor with a const object apparently pointing to const data becomes an object which cannot alter the pointed-to data.

Comment: If you ponder the existence of `iterator` and `const_iterator`, and which one can be constructed from the other, and one potential approach becomes possible. In any case, you can't "ensure that a copy constructor with a const object apparently pointing to const data becomes an object which cannot alter the pointed-to data". C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: You don’t have to copy a `const std::shared_ptr<…>` to obtain non-const access to the referenced object: `*` will do that already.  Pointers just have two (or more) places to put `const`; it *is* a shame that the type system doesn’t let us automatically convert smart pointers in all the ways that we can raw pointers, but you can definitely write `std::const_pointer_cast<const …>(sp)` to enforce const through a `std::shared_ptr`, so it might fall short of being a “fundamental problem”.