# Return an immutable vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, immutability, const-pointer

I have the following object:

```
class Container {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>& items() { return m_items; }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> m_items;
};
```

I'd like to use `const` to make this whole object immutable but still provide access to `items()`, even though it's using pointers internally. E.g. declare `void doSomething(const Container& container)` and be sure that the code doesn't accidentally change its contents.

How can I write `const auto& items() const { ... }` to allow read-only access to the vector of items without the caller being able to modify any of the items, the pointers or the vector?

---

**Attempt #1**: The first step is...

```
    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>& items() const { return m_items; }

...

void doSomething(const Container& container)
{
    // Good: const container, can't do this
    container.items().clear();

    // Good: const unique_ptr, can't do this
    container.items()[0].reset();

    // Bad: non-const items
    *container.items()[0] = ...;
}
```

**Attempt #2**: What I really want is this, but it's UB because there's no guarantee that the const type has the same memory layout (and maybe other reasons?).

```
    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Item>>& items() const {
        return reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Item>>&>(m_items);
        //                                                        ^_________ change unique_ptr type
    }
```

**Attempt #3**: A rather terrible alternative is to construct and return a temporary vector. Equally bad would be to cache and maintain this duplicate vector.

```
    std::vector<const Item*> items() const {
        return {m_items.begin(), m_items.end()};
    }
```

**Attempt #4**: Implement something like `std::span`, but have the iterator only return const references. In this case it would need to unwrap the std::unique_ptr. This would work, but it's a fair bit of effort for just one use-case. Maybe well into the realm of over-engineering too?

There might be some unexpected side effects for code expecting certain types and not using `auto` when iterating, but I'm ok with that.

---

[EDIT] This is vaguely similar to the concept of a deep copy. Following the term lead here:

- [How to make a deep-const pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505046/how-to-make-a-deep-const-pointer)
- [Propagate constness to data pointed by member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729820/propagate-constness-to-data-pointed-by-member-variables)
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const

Comment: In order to achieve your desired behavior, your `items` must return a custom proxy object that meets all requirements for a C++ container, with the desired semantics. There is no single incantation that can be uttered in order to achieve this, a huge pile of code must be written (but it's doable). What is your skill level, and knowledge level of C++ containers, and container requirements?

Comment: Attempt #2 is UB when the returned pointer is accessed, regardless of memory layout.

Comment: #4 sounds like the correct approach to me. It also removes `std::vector` from the interface. If the user isn't supposed to be able to modify the container, then the container should probably not be part of the interface either. Returning an unspecified range type that has the desired behavior shouldn't be too difficult, e.g. a `views::transform` should be enough.

Comment: You could return a range view of references to const items